# How to auto-mock a container (e.g. IList) in MOQ without extensions/contrib

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, automocking

i wonder if it is possible to auto mock
a container in MOQ without any additions to the MOQ lib.
I am having problems finding a clean way to automock an IList.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to mock an IList?  Just create a List<T> and use that.  Is there some behavior of the IList you're looking to test?

Comment: It isn't clear from your question what you are having trouble achieving. There may be valid reasons to mock an IList - but what do you mean by 'automock'?

Comment: I am referring to this -> http://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking. Trying to mock a container

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Answer to your question: No.**

Do you really need to mock IList?

Mocks are typically used to:

- To test behaviour (via expectations) rather than results.
- To abstract away complex or heavy dependencies.
- To simplify your tests code by easily returning a desired value.
- To test only your class under tests.

You could for example mock a repository that access a database. Normally your tests would not mock a list but rather have a mocked object return a list with the data that you need for your test.

ie:

```
var aList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var mockService = new Mock<IMyService>();
mockService.Setup(mock => mock.GetFooList()).Returns(aList);
```

It might help clarify your question if you specify why you need to mock a container.